# Is it possible that "何度も" could be translated as "Nothing or anything"?

Tags: translation

So I was reading "BTS, No more dream" Japanese lyrics, and I encountered this line:

> "You tell me [何度もやれ!]

And it was translated like this:

> You tell me [I can't do anything!]

I looked up 何度も in dictionary and it was translated as "Many times or Often".
So can you tell me why does it mean "anything or nothing" here?

Thanks in advance.
Shahrzad Parvizi.

Comment: umm... are you saying that you looked up the Japanese lyrics to a Korean rap song... and then the English translation of those Japanese lyrics?? I can only imagine that mistakes were introduced at each level... With a 3 step translation of a song, there's no telling what the original meaning was supposed to be.

Comment: Those lyrics were definitely translated wrong.

Comment: @ericfromabeno You are absolutely right!

Comment: @ericfromabeno I have also noticed that the translation of some lines are wrong!  And yes, as you siad the three level translation is probably the reason of that! And I also suspect that the lyrics has been written by a non-native Japanese speaker!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the translation you looked up is wrong.  If anything, it might be related to the fact that this is from a Korean (i.e. non-native speaker) rap song. (Thanks for pointing that out @ericfromabeno!)

Lets break it down:

**何度も:** [many times over/often](https://jisho.org/search/nandomo)

**やれ:** imparitive form of [やる](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%81%A3%E3%82%8B), or `to do; to undertake; to perform`

So I would run the translation as follows:

> 何度もやれ！
>   Do it often!

Or, in terms of the feel:

> Keep doing it!